# Codeigniter link issue

Tags: codeigniter

Hello all first sorry for the stupid question.

I am making a small job board with codeigniter, and i ran into a problem.

On the main page it lists the jobs and when i click on them it redirect to the details page with the infos about the job.

My problem is i made a category filter where they can browse the jobs by clicking on a category, and on that page when i click the link for the details its giving me this url: **localhost/jobboard/lists/category/lists/details/test-job** insted of this **localhost/jobboard/lists/details/test-job** <-- this is the right one.

```
<li>
        <a href="<?php base_url(); ?>lists/details/<?php echo $res->job_link ?>">
            <span><?php echo $res->job_title ?></span>
            <p><?php echo $job_type ?> | <?php echo $res->job_location ?> | <?php echo $res->company_name ?></p>
        </a>
    </li>
```

and the above code should not show this: **localhost/jobboard/lists/category/lists/details/test-job*
Could please soeone give me a hint? because i tried a few things and im totally clueles

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Darn i got it, i forgot to echo the base url....